# Markdown escape of backquote doesn't work in comments

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

This doesn't work in comments on Stack Overflow but works in answers and questions:

``` `` (let ((name (gensym))) `(list `(list ,,name)))`` ```

It give this output in question/answers:

`` (let ((name (gensym))) `(list `(list ,,name))) ``

but in comments it just quote first list. See comment.

Comment: reference: `` (let ((name (gensym))) `(list `(list ,,name)))``

Comment: I tried applying code formatting to three backticks in a comment recently and couldn't get it working. I settled on three backticks without code formatting, that seemed to display fine ( ``` ), but that's useless for other cases like yours.

Comment: @Stijn I've just added comment and I written `'` instead and needed to write explanation why there is single quote.

Comment: Might be by-design, considering comments use [mini-Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments – `(let ((name (gensym))) \`(list \`(list ,,name)))`; you have to write `\\`` to get `\``.